# How do I solve $x^3 - 2x + 2 \ge 3 - x^2$?

Tags: inequality, cubics

I believe there will be values of $x$ for which the inequality $x^3 - 2x + 2 \ge 3 - x^2$ is true and values for which it is not true, because:

- *LHS asymptotically increases but RHS decreases for increasingly positive values of $x$*
- *LHS asymptotically decreases faster than RHS for increasingly negative values of $x$*

But I don't know how to reason much further about $x^3 - 2x + 2 \ge 3 - x^2$.

My idea is that if I get the inequality in a form I can reason about, I can determine what values of $x$ will satisfy the condition. I can reason about

$$\frac{a}{b} > 0$$

since either $a,b > 0$ or $a,b < 0$ for $\frac{a}{b} > 0$.

I can also reason about the signs of $a,b$ if they are expressed as a product of factors, since any even multiple of negative factors gives a positive (or zero) product. I think this will put me in a good spot to reason about what conditions must be met for the signs to satisfy the inequality $\frac{a}{b} > 0$ (although in my case, I am including zero).

Thus, my plan is to transform the inequality into the form LHS = `a quotient of factorised terms` and RHS = 0. But I'm not sure how.

Comment: You can look for points where the two sides are equal.  The rational root theorem says they are not rational.  A little [searching](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E3-2x%2B2%3D3-x%5E2) says they are relatively small.  You can then find the crossovers numerically.

Comment: As you observed, $\frac{a}{b} > 0$ tells you that $a$ and $b$ have the same sign. And that's all it tells you. You could equally well say $ab>0.$ I can't see how knowing two things have the same sign is going to help you decide that one of these polynomials is greater than the other. The method that seems obvious to me is to subtract $3-x^2$ from both sides of the inequality and then solve for $x^3+x^2-2x-1\geq0.$

Comment: The roots of the equation $x^3-2x+2=3-x^2$ can be written as $$\frac{2 \sqrt{7}\, \cos \! \left(\frac{\arctan \left(3 \sqrt{3}\right)}{3}+\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}\right)}{3}-\frac{1}{3}$$ for $k = 0,1,2$.

Comment: @DavidK I was thinking that knowing how the signs of the factors of $\frac{a}{b}$ will behave for different values of $x$ will tell me when the inequality ($\frac{a}{b} \ge0)$ is satisfied. Such as knowing the factors of $\frac{a}{b}$ when $a = x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1$ and $b=1$, which is the construction you suggest for approaching the problem. Does that clarify, or do you still think it is an irrelevant consideration?

Comment: @RossMillikan: What does it mean to find something numerically? What is an alternative to finding something numerically (not saying it is applicable here - just a conceptual question)?

Comment: @DavidK I could have said $ab > 0$; the same type of reasoning applies to this, and thus could be used to suggest a plan of attack. If all of it seems dodgy and irrelevant, maybe it was a bad plan. But I was trying to get some purchase on the problem.

Comment: The opposite is when you find an expression for the root algebraically.  Some equations you can do that, others you cannot.  If you can't, you can approximate the roots by numeric algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^3+x^2-2x-1 \ge 0$$

---

First, let's solve the equation: $$x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$$ Let's say $x=y-\frac{1}{3}$ :
$$y^3-\frac{7}{3}y-\frac{7}{27}=0$$ We know that the: $(m+n)^3-3mn(m+n)-(m^3+n^3)=0$. Based on this, let's say $y=m+n$. Now let's calculate the following system of equations: $$\begin{cases} 3mn=\frac{7}{3} \\ m^3+n^3=\frac{7}{27} \end{cases}$$ To solve this system of equations, it is necessary to solve the equation below: $$m^3+\left(\frac{7}{9m}\right)^3=\frac{7}{27}$$ $$\frac{729m^6-189m^3+343}{729m^3}=0$$ Substitute $t$ for $m^3$ $$729t^2-189t+343=0$$ From here: $$t=\frac{7\sqrt{3} i}{18}+\frac{7}{54}$$ $$t=-\frac{7\sqrt{3} i}{18}+\frac{7}{54}$$ Since $m=t^3$ ,the solutions are obtained by solving the equation for each $t$ and variable $m \neq 0$:
$$m=\frac{{\sqrt{7}e}^\frac{-\arctan(3\sqrt{3})i+2πi}{3}}{3}$$
$$m=\frac{{\sqrt{7}e}^\frac{-\arctan(3\sqrt{3})i+4πi}{3}}{3}$$
$$m=\frac{{\sqrt{7}e}^\frac{\arctan(3\sqrt{3})i}{3}}{3}$$
$$m=\frac{{\sqrt{7}e}^\frac{-\arctan(3\sqrt{3})i}{3}}{3}$$
$$m=\frac{{\sqrt{7}e}^\frac{\arctan(3\sqrt{3})i+2πi}{3}}{3}$$
$$m=\frac{{\sqrt{7}e}^\frac{\arctan(3\sqrt{3})i+4πi}{3}}{3}$$
We can find $n$ using $m$, $y$ using $m$ and $n$, and $x$ using $y$:

$$x_1=\frac{ -\sqrt{7}cos\left( \frac{arccos\left( \frac{\sqrt{7}}{14} \right) }{3} \right) -\sqrt{21}sin\left( \frac{arccos\left( \frac{\sqrt{7}}{14} \right) }{3} \right)-1}{3} \approx −1.801937736$$

$$x_2=\frac{ 2\sqrt{7}cos\left( \frac{arccos\left( \frac{\sqrt{7}}{14} \right) }{3} \right) -1}{3} \approx 1.246979604$$

$$x_3=\frac{ \sqrt{21}sin\left( \frac{arccos\left( \frac{\sqrt{7}}{14} \right) }{3} \right) -\sqrt{7}cos\left( \frac{arccos\left( \frac{\sqrt{7}}{14} \right) }{3} \right)-1}{3} \approx −0.445041868$$ So we have to solve the following inequality: $$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3) \ge 0$$

---

$$(x+1,8)(x-1,25)(x+0,45)\ge 0$$
$$x \in \left[-\frac{9}{5},-\frac{9}{20}\right] \cup \left[\frac{5}{4},+∞\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Solve the cubic to find $x = -1.8, -.445, 1.25$.

[image]

Comment: What method did you use to solve the cubic?

Comment: See here:  https://www.wikihow.com/Solve-a-Cubic-Equation